# NServiceBus - Handler multiple time execution issue

Tags: .net-core, nservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am facing some issues with the NServiceBus Handler. The handler is processing messages multiple times. I have added the code.

```
 .UseNServiceBus(context =>
            {
                var appInsightsOptions = configuration.GetRequiredSection("AppInsights").Get<AppInsightsOptions>();
                NServiceBus.Logging.ILoggerFactory nservicebusLoggerFactory = new ExtensionsLoggerFactory(loggerFactory: new SerilogLoggerFactory());
                NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.UseFactory(loggerFactory: nservicebusLoggerFactory);
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName);
                endpointConfiguration.EnableApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration(appInsightsOptions.InstrumentationKey));

                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
                transport.ConnectionString(GetTransportConnectionString(configuration));
                //transport.Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.TransactionScope);
                endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
                endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<CosmosPersistence>()
                    .CosmosClient(new CosmosClient(cosmosConnectionString))
                    .DatabaseName(configuration.GetConnectionString("DATABASENAME"))
                    .DefaultContainer(containerName: "sagastore", partitionKeyPath: "/id")
                    .DisableContainerCreation();

                endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
                endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
                endpointConfiguration.AuditSagaStateChanges(serviceControlQueue: "audit");
                endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

                return endpointConfiguration;

            }
```

The handler class

```
public async Task Handle(SomeCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        try
        {   
            await DoSomeAction(message, context);
            
            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {}
    }
```

Here, this DoSomeAction method will have some logic to make API calls and db calls to store this info. The same message comes to this handler before the previous method executes the DoSomeAction method.

I am using NServiceBus 7.7.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `DoSomeAction` method and the time it takes. By default, NSB will set up the input queue to be `MaxLockDuration` 5 minutes, the maximum possible lease time with ASB today. Either the setting on the queue was changed to something substantially lower or the aforementioned method takes longer than 5 minutes.

An additional setting to validate is [Prefetching](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/configuration#controlling-the-prefetch-count). The defaults are reasonable but perhaps it's too high for your scenario and needs to be reduced or disabled. But first, I'd validate the lock aspect.